# Reused code to read from file causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS only in second class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I use this code in two different files to fill the `categories` array from a string of text from a text file, in which entries are separated by double pipes.

In the first file, my `appViewController` class, everything is fine. In the second, `popoverViewController`, the program bombs with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the `arrayWithArray:` line. Declarations for `categories`, `tempArray`, `diskfile`, and `textFromFile` are the same in both interface files.

`NSLog` tracers and breakpoints confirmed values of variables are the same down to that last fatal line. The popover contains a picker, so picker delegate and datasource protocols are in place. That's the only difference. Can anyone explain what might be going on?

```
categories=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;

NSMutableString *textFromFile=[[NSString alloc] init];  

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Categories" ofType: @"txt"];

if (filePath) {
  textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

  categories=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[textFromFile componentsSeparatedByString: @"||"]];
}
```

Comment: Can you add the crash stack trace? I'd also add "self." infront of all your properties; if they were defined as retain or strong it will retain them for you too. EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually occurs (to me) when trying to access an item that is already released. What bugs me is that you claim to have identical code in a different file that does work.... hence, the logs please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: Or hit Cmd-I in Xcode 4 to profile with Instruments, choose the Zombies instrument, and visualize the problem with a lot more fidelity (including malloc history).

Comment: Thanks, chown. I am ashamed and must apologize. What I described seems impossible, and it was. It was the NEXT line that caused the problem, a line that was different (of course) in the two routines. But I'm still stuck, so I'll have to make another question. Thanks again. I can use your suggestion.